# Other fields gets updated to blank as I call set State, Is there a way by which TextFormFields won't become Blank as i call set state

Tags: flutter

I know these fields are getting updated to blank because i am calling the set state method, but if i don't call the set state method in my toggle button the values won't change.

So is there a way by which i can use my toggle button and the TextFormFields won't get updated to blank

This is where the values are

```
class _AddPostState extends State<AddPost> {
  List<bool> _typeSelection = [false, false, false];
  String title = "";
  String type = "";
```

This is the field which gets updated as i press the Toggle Button

```
TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter Title",
                        labelText: "Title",
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Enter an Title';
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        title = value;
                      },
                    ),
```

This is the button

```
ToggleButtons(
                           
                            onPressed: (int newIndex) {
                              if (newIndex == 0) {
                                type = "Dog";
                                print(type);
                              }
                              if (newIndex == 1) {
                                type = "Cat";
                                print(type);
                              }
                              if (newIndex == 2) {
                                type = "Bird";
                                print(type);
                              }
                              setState(() {
                                for (int index = 0;
                                    index < _typeSelection.length;
                                    index++) {
                                  if (index == newIndex) {
                                    _typeSelection[index] = true;
                                  } else {
                                    _typeSelection[index] = false;
                                  }
                                }
                              });
```

Comment: Add `initialValue: type` as parameter of your `TextFormField` or add a `TextEditingController` to it.

Comment: Perfectly worked for me  Thanks enzo for your answer